# Intel App-Framework -displaying JSON data

Tags: android, jquery, cross-platform, appframework

How to display JSON coming from php in intel App Framwork app. I have tried `.getJSON()` and `.getJSONP()` methods. Is there any full guide explaining these methods and how to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are documentations for [$.getJSON()](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/api2/#%24_getJSON) and [$.jsonP()](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/api2/#%24_jsonP)

Answer (score 0):

found the answer .

```
  function getRaceData() {
 var postBody = "";

   postBody = "rid="+theRID;

   var parameters = new AppMobi.Device.RemoteDataParameters();
   parameters.url = "http://MyWebSite.com/php_src/getRaceData.php";
   parameters.id = "1007";
   parameters.method = "POST";
  parameters.body = postBody;       

   jq.ui.showMask('loading race data');
   AppMobi.device.getRemoteDataExt(parameters);
   }
   //then somewhere in your event handler, check the ID of the response and process the     JSON....
  case 1007:   //got race data   
 var raceData = jq.parseJSON(event.response);

 jq("#raceRCList").hide();

 jq("#raceRCname").html(raceData.race_name);
  jq("#raceRCdate").val(raceData.date);
 jq("#raceRCstart").val(raceData.start_time);

  jq("#raceRCData").show();

 break;
```